# How to make it possible to debug android 64-bit app in Embarcadero RAD Studio 10.3.3?

Tags: android, delphi, debugging, 64-bit, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm using `Delphi` 10.3.3 Rio to build an app for Android from an existing project. Delphi is installed on `Windows 64-bit` Ultimate.

I was able to run and debug the project under the `Android 32-bit` configuration, but when I try to do the same under the `64-bit` configuration, nothing will work. My app stops at the splash screen, and Delphi stops debugging like the app was terminated. I've tried to build an empty project and it runs normally, but debugging is not working.

I've installed the bug fix "30904 RAD Studio 10.3.3 Android Debugger Patch" along with the other 9 bug fixes, but the result is the same.

Here are my SDK settings:

SDK:

[image]

NDK:

[image]

NDK lib paths:

[image]

Java paths:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update to 10.4. Debugging works there under Android x64

Comment: The problems with updating Delphi is that all updates (hot fixes, minor, major updates) cost a yearly subscription. If your update subscription is out for a 1 year, you must pay for 2 years of subscription to "catch up" to where you left off according to Saba Khan - saba.khan@embarcadero.com whom is a Customer Renewals Representative.  There can not be any lapse in subscriptions.